# RDP into a CentOS VM deployed through Hyper-V on Windows 10?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, centos, hyper-v

I have a CentOS VM running using Hyper-V and would like to connect to it through RDP.

I have setup the Hyper-V switch to use an external network through my physical machine's LAN connection.

The VM can utilize the network no problem, but I am unsure what address to tell RDP to connect to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your Hyper-V guest is non-Microsoft it won't have RDP capability out-of-the-box, thus why you can't just "RDP" to it.

If you require to use Microsoft's RDP protocol then you will need to install an RDP server on the guest OS.

Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/use-remote-desktop

Although my source is for Azure it rings true for any Hyper-V (and other VM products too) guest.

The source above is suggesting [for Linux at least] to install `xrdp` which is an open-source RDP server that should allow you to use Windows built-in RDP client (mstsc.exe) to connect to your guest OS. A simple Google for `xrdp centos` shows a few articles of people who have installed it:

Source: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=xrdp+centos&oq=xrdp+centos&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1576j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

To add and complete my answer in respect to your final question: You will need to connect to the IP or hostname of the guest OS itself. If you do `ifconfig` on your CentOS terminal then you will see the IP address for your `ethx` (probably eth0) which you should recognise as your chosen subnet (192.168.x.x, 10.x.x.x etc.).